# Debugging my code

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter

I am new to python and am trying to create an application that displays different information like a clock, current news, notice board etc.

I got the clock to work however I am encountering a few bugs. One is that a smaller window launches when the application does. I thought this was something to do with the `self.root = tk.Tk()` in the initialisation however doing anything to this line produces errors.

The other bug is that while the background image (`0.png`) used to fill up the entire screen as it is the same size as my monitor, when I added the clock to the application, the image is shifted to the bottom right of the screen, leaving a small white line to the top and left of the screen. I have tried to fix this by messing with the `panel.pack` changing it to `grid` and `place` however both of this did nothing to the lines. I feel like something is overwriting this line.

None of these bugs are showing up in the console and I don't know what to do. Here is the code I am running:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
import time
import tkinter as tk
class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.label = tk.Label(text="",font=('comic',50,'bold'),bg = '#464545',fg = '#1681BE')
        self.label.place(height = 206,width = 487, x = 1384, y = 824)       
        self.update_clock()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update_clock(self):
       now = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
       self.label.configure(text=now)

       self.root.after(1000, self.update_clock)


root = Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("0.png"))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.overrideredirect(1)
app = App()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
root.mainloop()
```

I hope someone can find what's wrong with it because I certainly can't!

Comment: what bugs ? what errors ? always put in question full error message (Traceback). Don't expect that we will run your code. Many problems cam be resolve only reading (full) error message.

Comment: `tkinter` can have only one `tk.Tk()` window - if you need ssecond then use `tk.Toplevel()`. `tkinter` needs one `mainloop()` - it is program "engine" (like in car - it needs only one engine - it doesn't matter how many people you drive) - if you have more mainloops then there is problem with values in variables/widgets.

Comment: you could add screenshot to show problem. And add in question information what system do you use and how do you run it - manually in console, in IDLE, clicking in icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `App` class inherit from `Tk`, you don't need to create another root window. So I gathered all your code inside the `App` class. When I use an image the side of my screen, I don't see any line at the top or at the left of the screen, so I hope it will work for you as well.

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
import time
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        # call the __init__ method of Tk class to create the main window
        tk.Tk.__init__(self) 
        # background image
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("0.png"))
        panel = Label(self, image=img)
        panel.pack()
        # clock
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="", font=('comic',50,'bold'),
                              bg='#464545', fg='#1681BE')
        self.label.place(height=206, width=487, x=1384, y=824)       
        self.update_clock()
        # window geometry
        w, h = self.winfo_screenwidth(), self.winfo_screenheight()
        self.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.mainloop()

    def update_clock(self):
        now = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        self.label.configure(text=now)
        self.after(1000, self.update_clock)

app = App()
```